# run threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the next code:

```
    public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        NewSmartThread n = new NewSmartThread("ST");
        try{
            n.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println( "Умный поток был прерван" );
        }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

class NewSimpleThread extends Thread {

    public NewSimpleThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void run(){
            try {
                for(int i =1; i<6; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " : " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + "был прерван.");
            }
        System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
}
}

class NewSmartThread extends Thread {
    //final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
    //final CountDownLatch finish = new CountDownLatch(2);

    public NewSmartThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        //s1.split("(?<=\\G..)")

        NewSimpleThread n1 = new NewSimpleThread("1");
        NewSimpleThread n2 = new NewSimpleThread("2");
        NewSimpleThread n3 = new NewSimpleThread("3");

        n1.start();
        n2.start();
        n3.start();
        try{

            Thread.sleep(3000);


            n1.join();
            n2.join();
            n3.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread " + "broke.");
        }
        System.out.println("Smart thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
    }
}
```

And I have the next result:

```
>     Thread 2 : 1
>     Thread 3 : 1
>     Thread 1 : 1
>     Thread 3 : 2
>     Thread 1 : 2
>     Thread 2 : 2
>     Thread 2 : 3
>     Thread 1 : 3
>     Thread 3 : 3
>     Thread 2 : 4
>     Thread 1 : 4
>     Thread 3 : 4
>     Thread 1 : 5
>     Thread 2 : 5
>     Thread 3 : 5
>     Thread 1 closed.
>     Thread 2 closed.
>     Thread 3 closed.
>     Smart thread ST closed.
>     Hello World!
```

But if I use block synchronized in the next code:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        NewSmartThread n = new NewSmartThread("ST");
        try{
            n.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println( "Умный поток был прерван" );
        }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

class NewSimpleThread extends Thread {
    private static final Object monitor = new Object();
    public NewSimpleThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (monitor) {
            try {
                monitor.wait();
                for(int i =1; i<6; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " : " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
        }
    }

    public static void doNotifyAll(){
        synchronized (monitor) {
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
class NewSmartThread extends Thread {

    public NewSmartThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        NewSimpleThread n1 = new NewSimpleThread("1");
        NewSimpleThread n2 = new NewSimpleThread("2");
        NewSimpleThread n3 = new NewSimpleThread("3");

        n1.start();
        n2.start();
        n3.start();
        try{

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            NewSimpleThread.doNotifyAll();

            n1.join();
            n2.join();
            n3.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread " + "broke.");
        }
        System.out.println("Smart thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
    }
}
```

And have the next result:

> ```
> Thread 3 : 1 
> Thread 3 : 2 
> Thread 3 : 3 
> Thread 3 : 4 
> Thread 3 : 5 
> Thread 3 closed. 
> Thread 2 : 1 
> Thread 2 : 2 
> Thread 2 : 3 
> Thread 2 : 4 
> Thread 2 : 5 
> Thread 2 closed. 
> Thread 1 : 1 
> Thread 1 : 2 
> Thread 1 : 3 
> Thread 1 : 4 
> Thread 1 : 5 
> Thread 1 closed. 
> Smart thread ST closed. 
> Hello World!
> ```

But I need the result like in the first example. And can't use some features like CountDownLatch - only synchronized block(It is lab experiment and it is a requirenment)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your two examples are fundamentally different. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that on my signal all threads started simultaneously and the result was as in the previous example. In my case threads will start one after the other. First one and then 2 and so on

Comment: I agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis the question title and the explanation in itself do not actually reflect what you wish to achieve ?

Comment: In your first example, the threads are executing at the leisure of the  thread scheduler. With `wait` and `notify`, are you expecting some order?

Comment: No, but in the second exaple  threads executing one after the other, but I need, that they are executing at the leisure of the thread scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then the issue lies in how you have used the synchronized block in the second example.

You have `synchronized` the whole logic including the `for` loop inside synchronized block. While the correct way would be to just keep

```
synchronized(monitor){
    monitor.wait(); //excluding exception handling
}

//for loop logic
```

---

### Why?

Because you just want the threads to wait for the nod of the main thread to start working and once they get the notification you *dont want* the logic to be executed in `synchronized` manner and so *release the monitor*. Because you hold the monitor while `for` loop, no other thread is able to proceed until the one holding it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Narendra Pathai.

The ended variant of my code the next:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        NewSmartThread n = new NewSmartThread("ST");
        try{
            n.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println( "Умный поток был прерван" );
        }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}

class NewSimpleThread extends Thread {
    private static final Object monitor = new Object();
    public NewSimpleThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            Latch.awaitZero();
            for(int i =1; i<6; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " : " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
    }

    public static void doNotifyAll(){
        synchronized (monitor) {
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
class NewSmartThread extends Thread {

    public NewSmartThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        NewSimpleThread n1 = new NewSimpleThread("1");
        NewSimpleThread n2 = new NewSimpleThread("2");
        NewSimpleThread n3 = new NewSimpleThread("3");

        n1.start();
        n2.start();
        n3.start();
        try{

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Latch.doNotifyAll();

            n1.join();
            n2.join();
            n3.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread " + "broke.");
        }
        System.out.println("Smart thread " + this.getName() + " closed.");
    }
}

class Latch {
    private static final Object synchObj = new Object();

    public static void awaitZero() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
                synchObj.wait();
        }
    }
    public static void doNotifyAll() {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
                synchObj.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I added class:

```
class Latch {
    private static final Object synchObj = new Object();

    public static void awaitZero() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
                synchObj.wait();
        }
    }
    public static void doNotifyAll() {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
                synchObj.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

instead

```
class NewSimpleThread extends Thread {
    private static final Object monitor = new Object();
```

Comment: Why keep everything `static` in `Latch`? Make them non static and share a common reference among all the thread instances. Just a nugget.

Comment: Not much of a problem in this case, but as a practice it is good not to keep things static unless necessary.